# Laravel SQS Queue, How To Access Queue Properties

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, queue, amazon-sqs

I have SQS working with Laravel. All works well but I really need to be able to access the Queue properties. I know AWS/SQS provides these methods and I see protected methods when I look at the contents of

`Queue::getSqs()`

But not seeing any native Laravel way to access the queue attributes. How can I access them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct - they are protected methods. But when you run Queue::getSqs() - it is returning the underlying SQS instance - which means you have access to those methods.

So this works:

```
$list = Queue::getSqs()->listQueues();
```

As does this:

```
$attr = Queue::getSqs()->getQueueAttributes(array('QueueUrl' => 'string'));
```

A [full list of available commands is here at the AWS website](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/latest/class-Aws.Sqs.SqsClient.html).

Comment: @Phirschybar - did that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the API I believe you can access the raw attributes with Queue::getSqsJob(). Worth a shot, I can't test as I am on the road.

http://laravel.com/api/class-Illuminate.Queue.Jobs.SqsJob.html